# How to evaluate the integral $\int x^{|x|} dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the integration of $\int x^{|x|} dx$?
Actually through several google search finally I have found a solution for the problem $\int x^{x} dx$ using Gamma function function and I am hardly sure that the same method can be applied to solve the problem if $x^{x}$ is going to be replaced by $x^{|x|}$.

So, what is the appropriate approach to solve the problem $\int x^{|x|} dx$

Comment: What is the domain of $x^x$?

Comment: Just break the integral up. $|x|=-x$ for negative $x$.

Comment: if $x>0$, $x^{|x|}=x^x$, if $x<0$, $x^{|x|}=x^{-x}$,

Comment: @Yolbarsop as $x^x$ = $e^(xlnx)$ so can the domain be x<0? If not, then can the integral be reduced to $x^x$ form?

Comment: @rng70 It depends I think. If this is from real analysis when $x<0$, $x^x$ might not be real,  it is safe to stay in $x>0$. Otherwise, $x$ can be anywhere in the complex plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^x$ and $x^{-x}$ are not integrable in elementary terms. See [This theorem by Liouville.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) This theorem one way to approach that question.

This is obviously not something one would expect, and I too was surprised at this when I first asked myself your question.

It's possible (and a good exercise if you're interested) to find a closed form expression for the area under $x^x$ and $x^{-x}$ over the interval $[0,1]$. Spoilers:

$$\int_0^1x^xdx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}$$

Once you've done that, you can do essentially the same for $x^{-x}$.
This, as far as I know, is the closest one could come to an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that this is for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ you will still run into problems with the output of the function being complex for $x<0$ since you will have a negative number to a non-integer power, so in that respect this function is very similar to the functions $x^x$ and $x^{-x}$ so as others have suggested there are many papers on that integral so I suggest that you use those in this manner:
$$\int x^{|x|}dx=\begin{cases}\int x^xdx&x>0\\\int x^{-x}dx&x<0\end{cases}$$
as for at $x=0$, both cases will return the same result as it can be proved that $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$